# Prototype bean injection using type

Tags: java, spring, spring-boot, spring-bean

I am new to spring world. While learning about Prototype bean, I came across a weird response.

- I defined a bean with scope prototype

```
@Configuration
public class BeanConfiguration {

    @Bean
    @Scope(value = BeanDefinition.SCOPE_PROTOTYPE)
    public MessageService configureEmailMessageService() {
        return new EmailMessageService();
    }
}
```

- I am injecting the bean using Match By Type.

```
public static void main(String[] args) {
        AnnotationConfigApplicationContext context = new AnnotationConfigApplicationContext(BeanConfiguration.class);
        MessageService email = context.getBean(EmailMessageService.class);
        System.out.println(email.hashCode());
    }
```

While executing this, I am getting

> No qualifying bean of type 'com.my.personal.project.spring.di.bean.services.EmailMessageService' available

But when I inject using name as shown below, it's working.

```
MessageService email = context.getBean("configureEmailMessageService");
```

My question is : **Isn't it possible to inject prototype bean through Type ? Or am I missing something ?**

Thanks

Comment: Because a proxy is being generated for your class. That proxy is based on the information available at configuration time, which is only the method signature. SO you get a `MessageService` proxy and not a `EmailMessageService` proxy due to the return type of your `@Bean` method.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You are searching for a bean of type `EmailMessageService`, but in the `BeanConfiguration` class you are exposing a method that return a generic `MessageService`.

You need to get a bean (with the method getBean) that is a `MessageService.class`.

Try to change the signature of method

```
@Bean
@Scope(value = BeanDefinition.SCOPE_PROTOTYPE)
public MessageService configureEmailMessageService() {
    return new EmailMessageService();
}
```

to

```
@Bean
@Scope(value = BeanDefinition.SCOPE_PROTOTYPE)
public EmailMessageService configureEmailMessageService() {
    return new EmailMessageService();
}
```

or change the row

```
MessageService email = context.getBean(EmailMessageService.class);
```

in

```
MessageService email = context.getBean(MessageService.class);
```

Comment: Thanks for the answer. But if I remove the bean scope, the mentioned code works fine. Is it something related to bean scope ?

Answer (score 0):

I think that we get this error "No qualifying bean of type", when we define many implementations of bean-like that :

```
@Bean
@Scope(value = BeanDefinition.SCOPE_PROTOTYPE)
public MessageService configureEmailMessageService1() {
    return new EmailMessageService1();
}

@Bean
@Scope(value = BeanDefinition.SCOPE_PROTOTYPE)
public MessageService configureEmailMessageService2() {
    return new EmailMessageService2();
}
```

So you have to check if you have many EmailMessageService Bean  !